# Suggestions for computing correlations between evaluators

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data

I have a data frame consisting of evaluations made by students of other student fellows. An excerpt of the evaluations data frame looks like this (columns are evaluators, rows correspond to the evaluated student):

```
       s1          s2    s3       s4
1       7           8    NA        8
2      NA           7     8       NA
3       9           6     6        8
4       9           9     7        7
5       9           8    NA        7
       ...
```

I want to know how evaluators are related to each other in terms of similarity of their non-NA assessment values. Would it be OK If I use `corrgram(evaluations)` or is it advisable to use some other method?

Thanks!

Comment: Your NA's are a problem. As you understand you can't make correlations between missing observations. Thus some of the students end up having high n and others low. You could either use correlations as you describe (corrgram or make a correlation table) or then use a correspondence analysis for instance. If you ended up using CA, you would need to delete all missing values in your data. This would lead to a lower n, but perhaps more trustworthy picture. Depends on how many NA's you have and if their distribution is biased.

Comment: Could you explain the mechanism by which some of the data became missing?  (I suspect this may provide useful clues to guide replies to the question.)

Comment: @whuber students were asked to evaluate their fellows' exercises (at least 10 evaluations from a total of ~30 possible exercises). So there are quite a lot of NAs in the dataframe.

Comment: @Largh thanks for you clarification. I'll try to delete my NA's and try again using the corrgram.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why the NAs are there, but it does suggest they might not be missing at random, which is a crucial distinction.

Comment: I'll try to explain the NA values with the aid of the example data that I've posted. For example, the evaluator s1 has decided to not evaluate exercise 2 from one of his colleagues, but has evaluated the rest (1,3,4 and 5), s2 has evaluated all of them (1 to 5), s3 on the other hand, has decided to evaluate 2,3 and 4 but not 1 and 5.  Hope that I've clarified the problem a little more.

Comment: @Juanan: Not sure if you're still here, but whuber's question is not *which*, but *why*. Did the evaluators know who did each exercise, so they might make choices based on their relationship with the colleague (or lack of relationship)? Or did the evaluators not know who did each exercise, so perhaps gravitated towards exercises with which they were more familiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty standard psychometric problem of [inter-rater agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability). The most popular measure is probably $\kappa$ (kappa):
$$
\kappa=\frac{{\rm P}[\mbox{agreement between raters}]-{\rm P}[\mbox{random agreement}]}{1-{\rm P}[\mbox{random agreement}]}
$$
It's somewhat similar to $R^2$ in that values close to 1 indicate good agreement, and values close to zero, little or no agreement.